# fastest way to traverse a tree structure in cpp with a stack

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack, iteration, eigen3

I've got a tree structure and a running example of how to iterate over it but as I'm a beginner when it comes to performance in coding, I wanted to ask if somebody knows a way to make it faster. 
Eigen3 is used to build vectors.

The struct:

```
    struct linkedBoxes{
        std::vector<Vector3r> points;
        std::vector<linkedBoxes*> boxes;
        int sideLength;
    };
```

And the algorithm:

```
    std::vector<Vector3r> integPoints;

    std::vector<linkedBoxes*> stack;
    stack.push_back(firstBox);

    vector<linkedBoxes*>::iterator iterator = stack.begin();

    while (iterator != stack.end()){
        if((*iterator)->boxes.size() == 0){
            for (int j = 0; j < (*iterator)->points.size(); ++j) {
                integPoints.push_back(point + (*iterator)->points[j]);
            }
        } else {

            for (int k = 0; k < (*iterator)->points.size(); ++k) {
                Vector3r tmpPoint = point + (*iterator)->points[k];
                if(computeDistance(tmpPoint) < 0){
                    const size_t diff = iterator - stack.begin();
                    stack.push_back((*iterator)->boxes[k]);
                    iterator = stack.begin() + diff;
                }
            }
        }

        ++iterator;
    }
```

Point is a vector which is given to the function and computeDistance returns a value between -1 and 1.
Does somebody knows a way to make this faster?

Bruno

Comment: Does this work? You push stuff to a "stack" but don't seem to ever pop anything. You also access arbitrary items of the "stack". This is not a stack at all.

Comment: Yes it does. I "walks" the stack up

Comment: A stack has three methods: pop, push, and top. A stack does not have iterators or indices or begin(). You may call your array "stack" but it isn't. It's an array.

Comment: You actually use your array as a *queue*, but you don't remove processed elements and you force array iterators to a place where they naturally don't work. May I suggest using std::deque instead? Your algorithm would then be actually readable.

Comment: Ok thanks for the idea. My question is based in the structure what would be the fastest option to iterate over it?

Comment: Deque should be faster and take less memory.

Comment: ok i will rewrite it